# Is there a way to make deductions about, or calculate exactly, each root of a polynomial if you know their sum and product? (Vieta's formulas)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is probably a trivial question, and I expect the answer to be: "No, not at all", but I just have to make sure. In a problem I'm working on that involves Vieta's formulas, I know the highest, second highest and second lowest order coefficients of a polynomial, and I know that polynomial's degree, $D$, so Vieta's formulas can tell be the sum of the roots $r_1+r_2+\cdots$ and their product too: $r_1\cdot r_2\cdot r_3\cdots$

Additionally, I know that the first $p$ roots are the naturals $0,1,2,\cdots,p$, and $p$ is always less than the degree of this polynomial, and usually much, much less - a closed form formula would be a bit unnecessary to give, but the degree has a Fibonnaci-like growth whereas $p$ grows linearly. I do not know for sure, but I can make a very confident guess that all the other roots are complex, and non-integers. Supposing this were true, does all this information allow me to deduce some of the roots based on my knowledge of $r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_p$?

I assume the equations $1+2+3+4+5+\cdots+p+r_{p+1}+r_{p+2}+\cdots+r_D=a$ and $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots p\cdot r_{p+1}\cdot r_{p+2}\cdots r_D=b$ are unsolvable even with knowledge of $p,a,b$ and $D$, but I want to make sure that there is nothing that can be deduced - because if deductions about the other roots can be made, that would be Once again, the reader is invited to build on my work. For whatever reason, I really like this puzzle and the fact that some progress can be made, that would be very useful to me!

More detail:

The polynomial will have rational coefficients always. Integer inputs give it integer outputs. The constant coefficient is zero, the linear, second highest and highest, coefficients are knowable. The others may be knowable but I’ll have to look into that, the process of finding them in the problem I’m working on is very messy.

Comment: Subtracting the known roots in the $a$ eqn, and dividing them out of the $b$ eqn, leaves the system $$r_{p+1}+r_{p+2}+\cdots+r_{p+k}=a'\qquad r_{p+1}r_{p+2}\cdots r_{p+k}=b'$$ Two such eqns allow for determining at most two unknowns, so having $k>2$ is problematic. If you know *all* coeffs are real, then you know that non-real roots come in conjugate pairs; if you happen to know the *signs* of all coeffs, then [Descartes' Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) might tell you something. ... Anyway, describing your polynomial in detail may elicit better advice.

Comment: @Blue all coefficients are rational, and the polynomial outputs integer values for integer input. The signs can be determined, but the only tractably knowable coefficients are the lowest order constant coefficient (which is always zero), the linear coefficient, and the highest order two coefficients. Thank you for the rule of signs, I’ll review that

Comment: Please add clarifications and context to the body of the question itself. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden. ... I'd still like to know more about your polynomial, and/or what motivates it. Readers may have different senses about what counts as "tractably knowable". (For instance, I occasionally wrestle with polynomials having thousands —even *hundreds* of thousands— of terms.)

Comment: @Blue impressive work. In the interest of community, I am working on an answer to a question that was posted on this forum but received no attention from anyone except myself. My answer as it stands is an in-progress answer, with lots of groundwork done but not a full answer found - yet! My partial answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4212156/815585)